# Filling a choice field with objects from a query

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a ModelForm, which I'm trying to have a **dynamic** select in it.

My ModelForm in forms.py:

```
class AuxiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Auxi
        fields = ["tipAux"]
        widgets = {
            'tipAux': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tipo'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'tipAux': 'Tipo',
        }
```

and I want to have a **choicefield** which should be dynamic, filling itself by a query from an other class called TipoAux.

TipoAux in models.py:

```
class TipoAux(models.Model):
    denom = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    def __str__(self):  # Python 3
        return self.denom
```

Conclusion: I'm my form I should have a **dynamic select** which collects its options from TipoAux class

Like this:

```
Options = (
    (1, 'First option',
    (2, 'Second option',
)
```

But getting its options from my DB, and not having to add them manually.

Comment: Good question! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have this structure you should follow and do the next steps:

Create a Model called **TipoAux**:

```
class TipoAux(models.Model):

    denom = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then immediately run **migrate** since the other table will depend on this (if you do not have this table yet).

Then create the other things like the other Model (this is what you are actually most interested in with your question):

```
class Auxi(models.Model):

    # we get the TipoAux choice values from the TipoAux table and creating a list of that
    all_tipoaux = TipoAux.objects.values()
    TIPAUX_CHOICES = [(d['id'], d['denom']) for d in all_tipoaux]

    tipAux = models.IntegerField(choices=TIPAUX_CHOICES, null=True, verbose_name='Tipo')
```

Then your **Form** (first just make it simple, do not use select widget and label yet, since it’s automatically created due to the model):

```
from .models import Auxi

class AuxiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Auxi
        fields = ["tipAux"]
```

Then your **view** something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import AuxiForm
from .models import Auxi

def tipo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuxiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myappname:index'))
    else:
        form = AuxiForm()
    return render(request, 'myappname/auxiform.html', {'form': form})
```

You have to `run migration` again to create the **Auxi table**

Then you will just create a `url path` to the view in `urls.py` and do not forget to register your models in the `admin.py`.

```
from .models import TipoAux, Auxi

admin.site.register(TipoAux)
admin.site.register(Auxi)
```

Then you have to go to your admin page of your site and **create some items in the TipoAux table for having some option values.**

And this is the visual end result of the above (recorded my results in gif):

[image]

I hope this will be in help of you. Cheers. ;)